# Find the dimensions of a square piece of cardboard given data of it folded into a square (cubic inches, etc.)

Tags: volume, quadratics

A box with a square base and no top is to be made from a square piece of cardboard 
by cutting 6 in. squares out of each corner and folding up the sides. The box needs to 
hold 1000 in3
. How big a piece of cardboard is needed?

Answer (score 1):

1. Let $x$ be the side length of the cardboard before cutting.
2. Determine the dimensions of the box in terms of $x$.
3. Use the results of step 2 to write the volume of the box in terms of $x$.
4. Set the expression from step 3 equal to 1000 and solve for $x$.

Comment: I got past the x^2 – 12x +36 = 166.6, and then I got x^2 –12x –130.6 = 0. Does this mean now that I have to find a number that multiples to be 130.6 and add to be 12?

Comment: @janeausten The base of the box is $x-12$, not $x-6$, since you cut $6$ inches from both sides.  So you should get $6(x^2 - 24x + 144) = 1000$.  Simplify, then use the quadratic equation to solve for $x$.